# data table v1.8.8 POSIX dates convert to numeric after 'by' operation

Tags: r, data.table, posixct

I was attempting to add a new column to a data table which would be of class POSIXct, but I found that the data keeps getting converted to numeric for some reason ... but only when I use 'by'.  Is this a bug, or a limitation, or am I doing something wrong?

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(rep(1,2), rep(2,2)), y=1:4)
dt[, z:=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01")]
>dt

   x y          z
1: 1 1 2014-01-01
2: 1 2 2014-01-01
3: 2 3 2014-01-01
4: 2 4 2014-01-01
```

So far so good...

```
dt <- data.table(x = c(rep(1,2), rep(2,2)), y=1:4)
dt[, z:=as.POSIXct("2014-01-01"), by=x]
>dt

   x y          z
1: 1 1 1388534400
2: 1 2 1388534400
3: 2 3 1388534400
4: 2 4 1388534400
```

Not what I was expecting!

Hmm.... I wonder... does data table grouping rely on lapply?  If so, it doesn't support POSIXct, because lapply does type conversions -- is that right?

Comment: Could you please paste your `sessionInfo()`? Thanks. I can't seem to replicate it in `v1.9.2` (or in `devel v1.9.3`).

Comment: Oh, it seems I'm running 1.8.8.  I guess I'm out of date

Comment: Oh yes, it's been ages. It was fixed long back. Edited title to reflect this.